# Android web view load javascript in random order / not loading

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I have an issue with a web view I'm using.
The javascript files used to render the view properly MUST be loaded in a specific order.
On browser (chrome mobile; safari desktop, ...) it works well.

However in my web view the result is unpredictable.

This is one of the latests failing run I had:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
                <title></title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
                <style>
                        body {
                                font-family: Monospace;
                                background-color: #000;
                                color: #fff;
                                margin: 0px;
                                overflow: hidden;
                        }
                </style>
                </head>
        <body>
                <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"></canvas>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script3.js"></script>
                <script src="js/script4.js"></script>
                ... More scripts...
        </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
   mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    //mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.24:8000/path/to/index.html");
```

The issue is that randomly, javascript files are interpreted in wrong order or just not loaded.

From my understanding, javascript MUST be loaded in declaration order.

Am I wrong ? 
Is there anything I can do to change that behavior ? (other than concatenating all JS together..)

Comment: try to save the `jquery` script locally and then run.

Comment: @Riad I can but actually I never had any jquery issue yet

Comment: @Riad I moved jQuery, and it's not loaded anymore when I use the web view (load well from browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts will work on the web site but for make it work on the android you need to load the scripts manually. See the function how it load the script from assets.

```
private void injectScriptFile(WebView view, String scriptFile) {
      InputStream input;
      try {
         input = getAssets().open(scriptFile);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
         input.read(buffer);
         input.close();

         // String-ify the script byte-array using BASE64 encoding !!!
         String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
         view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                      "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                      "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                      "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
         // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                      "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                      "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                      "})()");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

[See Here Example](https://codedump.io/share/aNZPEgd0v49w/1/android-web-view--inject-local-javascript-file-to-remote-webpage)

also make sure you enabled JS:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and the manifest ofcourse:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but i use a web server not a local file... 
Plus this does not explain why do I get inconsistent results.